# SQL Query for report

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I am working on a aggregate report and I have got so far with the data but I am unsure how to proceed from here. I get by with SQL but my skills are limited

I have the follow in a temp table

```
ID   Count  Action
2   23      Installed
2   12      Uninstalled
2   36      Unchanged
3   12      Installed
3   25      Unchanged
4   35      Installed
4   25      Unchanged
```

I want to convert this into this format

```
ID  Installed   Uninstalled Unchanged
2   23          12          36
3   12          0           36
4   35          0           25
```

I have no idea where to go or even how to start to achieve this and cannot find anything to point me in the right direction (Im sure its there somewhere)

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Do you want a `sum` for each `id`?  I don't see where you get the value for `id=3` and `unchanged`?  Also do you have a fixed number of `action` values?

Comment: If the is no unchanged as there isnt for id 3 or 4 it needs to be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  ID, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN "Action" = 'Installed' THEN Count END) AS 'Installed',
  MAX(CASE WHEN "Action" = 'Uninstalled ' THEN Count END) AS 'Uninstalled',
  MAX(CASE WHEN "Action" = 'Unchanged' THEN Count END) AS 'Unchanged'
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID;
```

Or using the SQL Server `PIVOT` table operator like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
   SELECT * FROM table
)t
PIVOT
(
   MAX("Count") FOR "Action" IN([Installed], [Uninstalled], [Unchanged])
) p
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo for both](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f16c/1)

However, for unknown number of `Action`s, you will have to select them dynamically like so:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Action) 
                    from Table1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @query = 'SELECT ID,  ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                SELECT * FROM Table1
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                MAX(count)
                FOR action IN (' + @cols + ')
             ) p ';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo(Dynamic Version)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f16c/4)

Comment: Ha, you beat me by a few seconds!

Comment: I wasn't expecting anyone to write the code for me :) Excellent, your first example works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: @Fred - Its my pleasure. You're welcome any time. See my edit, in case you want to write this query dynamically and not to write the values `[Installed], [Uninstalled], [Unchanged]` hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a pivot

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the documentation about it

The syntax is

```
SELECT <non-pivoted column>,
    [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,
    [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,

    ...

    [last pivoted column] AS <column name>
FROM
    (<SELECT query that produces the data>)
    AS <alias for the source query>
PIVOT
( 
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)
FOR
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],
    ... [last pivoted column])

) AS <alias for the pivot table>

<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pivots are good, but very slow at times.  Try it without one.

```
SELECT ID
    , SUM(CASE WHEN [Action] = 'Installed' THEN [Count] ELSE 0 END) AS Installed
    , SUM(CASE WHEN [Action] = 'Uninstalled' THEN [Count] ELSE 0 END) AS Uninstalled
    , SUM(CASE WHEN [Action] = 'Unchanged' THEN [Count] ELSE 0 END) AS Unchanged
FROM <table>
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: The reason the GROUP BY is going to work much faster than the pivot is because it's performing the entire operation in a single pass over the table, rather than an effective CROSS JOIN.